# How to use the refresh token with Google Sign-In API for iOS

Tags: ios, google-signin

We're successfully using Google Sign In to authenticate and access the data we need. However, our token will eventually expire.  The GIDAuthentication object includes a refresh token. We're wondering if the sign-in library is handling the refresh behind the scenes, perhaps as part of signIn or signInSilently.

The API documentation doesn't talk about refreshing the token, so I'm hoping someone can explain how the google library uses the refresh token.

Or, if we refresh the tokens in our code, should we only call signIn when we can no longer use a refresh token to get new tokens?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the api was added to the 2.1.0 sdk, GIDAuthentication refreshAccessTokenWithHandler.